# Marquee on TextView does not work after call to setText()

Tags: android

We are working on an App that needs to work on API19.
We are supposed to show a text over a VideoView and when the text is longer (than that can be fit inside the container) we would like to scroll/marquee the text horizontally.

Though the TextView has a property to specify Marquee, we could not get it working.

Here is the XML definition:

```
android:visibility="invisible"
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

Here is how it is made visible programmatically:

```
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
textView.setSelected(true);
textView.setEnabled(true);
```

I even tried to set all attributes programmatically instead of XML definitions. None of the attempts worked. There are many questions on this topic, I tried almost all the suggestions, yet this could not be made to work.

**Update:** 
It works fine if I don't call `textView.setText()` . From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765865/560449 it appears we can not get Marquee effect to continue working after a call to `textView.setText()` . Anyone know of a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just got rid of this issue a moment back and found no Rocket science involved here!

All you need to do is just set all the attributes programatically once you have called `setText()` in code.

For example

```
mTvTitle.setText("skjdfbaskjfdbkajbgjkbgjkdbgkjg");
        mTvTitle.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        mTvTitle.setSingleLine(true);
        mTvTitle.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(5);
        mTvTitle.setSelected(true);
```

Done! It's working way too better for me.

[SOF REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22796365/1149398)